# iTerm2 - copy mode with emacs bindings

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, iterm2

is it possible to change the copy-mode key-bindings in iTerm2? In particular I'd like to use the same key-bindings of emacs when navigating in iTerm2 when in copy-mode.